# Eclipse hot code replace is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hotswap

When I run my program in debug mode and try to use hot code replace feature, it just doesn't change anything in running application and there no error window is shown. I am using eclipse version 3.6.2, JVM 1.6 and Windows 7. I have "Build Automatically" checked, I unchecked "Abort build when build path errors occur", but nothing helps. (And I am not creating/deleting methods or something like that.)

Comment: Is the code being run in a hosted application server? Are you updating your code in the debug perspective or flipping back and forth between Java/Debug?

Comment: Code is running on my computer. I tried debug perspective and java perspective too.

Comment: More what I meant is ... within your IDE, how are you running the code? Hot swap only really comes into play if you have a long running program or set a breakpoint in a method.

Answer (score 2):

Check if *Build Automatically* is ticked (✓). This would Build your project automatically on Hot code replacement. This worked for me!

Comment: Wouldn't it be the other way around: hot code replacement _is triggered by_ project being rebuild!?

Comment: I know! So frustrating... Thank you so much for this answer @SGuru! +10000

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project. Go to properties->Java Build Path->Projects tab. See if there is any project dependency which does not exist. Remove those projects.

Try hot deployment again. For me that fixed the issue.